# Rearrange font sequence in home menu font drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How can I rearrange font sequence in home menu font drop down list in Excel 2007?

For example I want first position to be (Hindi language) font `KURTIDEV 11`, then second position to be English font `KAITI` and third no.... and so on.

Comment: Please do not write questions in capital letters. It's very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You may have noticed that at the top of the font menu there is a section Theme Fonts. I suspect the best that you are likely to achieve is adding KURTIDEV 11 and KAITI in there (but probably still in alphabetical order). I have not tested this but it seems a bit of a rigmarole to get the fonts in there, see http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/change-the-default-theme-HA010204550.aspx.